# Using array in if condition to know if the index is null in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have declared my array like this,

```
string[] timeArrivalArray = new string[10];
```

Now, let's assume that on every click on the add button, something is inserting there.

However I want to use an `if` condition to a certain index.
I want to use something like this

```
if (timeArrivalArray[] == [2]) {
}
```

Now whenever I click the `button`, the `timeArrivalArray[]` will check if it's already in the 2nd index and then execute the code. **tl;dr** I just want to use the `if` condition to the 2nd index, how can this be?

**EDIT**:
My problem is it's throwing excemption in the first increment. I have a `button` and something inserting from some variables. However, the code above is inserted in this

```
if (timeArrivalArray[] == [2]) {
    //*insert variable this*
} else {
    // *insert variable that*
}
```

**EDIT 2**:
Yes it's not the correct syntax and I just know how to do it. But the root of my problem is this

```
 DateTime theCalcu = DateTime.ParseExact(timeArrivalArray[2], "h:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It's throwing me `String reference not set to an instance of a String.`
Maybe because he can't find any index to the preceding indexes.
Any suggestion would do.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please add a code which shows what the button is supposed to do and reword the question and say what the problem is.

Comment: I don't understand this. Do you just want something like `if(timeArrivalArray[2]=="Whatever")`?

Comment: Gentlemen, I've edited my question. Sorry for the question but I can't think straight anymore.

Comment: the `if` logic check does not look right to me. are you sure this is C# ?

Comment: Yes it's c#, that's just a metaphoric way of how I visualize what I want to do. But before going to index number 2. it's throwing excemption because he can't find any value for index number 0 and 1

Comment: The code `timeArrivalArray[] == [2]` isn't valid C#.

Comment: You have not studied C# enough to warrant the code that conforms to [MCVE]. `if (timeArrivalArray[] == [2])` is wrong.

Comment: @Fiendcoder1 - You need to show a [mcve] for this issue.

Comment: Voting to close, as the question is very poor, no [MCVE], the code is not even C#.

Comment: I've edited my question, sorry.

Comment: That exception is coming because `timeArrivalArray[2]` is null. There is no surprise in there.

Comment: Ah so that's why, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

As much as I could comprehend from your post here is the logic I can think of. You can let me know what doesn't work out of it.

```
string[] timeArrivalArray = new string[10];
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (timeArrivalArray[2] == null)
            {
                //keep inserting into the array since 2nd index is null
            }
            else if (timeArrivalArray[2] != null && timeArrivalArray[2] == "someInputValue")
            {
                //2nd index is non null and some existing value found  
                //so do something else
            }
            else
            {
                //2nd index isn't null but input value wasn't found so keep inserting
            }
        }
```

Comment: checking for null is not really useful as the C#'s `new` would have all the array initialized to empty string.

Comment: Nope @t0mm13b. They will be initialized to null. string is a reference type.

Comment: woop... my bad, still, would be better to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)

Comment: Yep! I agree to that. `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is a better option if empty string is an invalid input which OP won't want to store in his array.

Answer (score 0):

> whenever I click the button. The timeArrivalArray[] will check if it's already in the 2nd index[...] I just want to use the if condition to the 2nd index

This sounds to me like you want to count up the index every time a click occurs. If so you should specify an index variable outside of the scope of the click event:

```
string[] timeArrivalArray = new string[10];

int index = 0;

public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   // make sure you are not running out of bounds    
    if(index < timeArrivalArray.Length)
    {    
        if(index == 2)
        {
            timeArrivalArray[index] = //*insert variable this*
        } 
        else 
        {
            // *insert variable that*
        }        
    }

    index ++; // walk to the next position    
}
```